# R Shiny renderPlot not respecting parent environment in for loop

Tags: r, loops, shiny, render

According to the help in renderPlot, renderPlot should be executing within the parent environment calling it. Nevertheless, in the minimal example hereafter I can't get to plot three different graphics :

```
library("shiny")
plotNames <- c("plot1", "plot2","plot3")
ui <- basicPage(uiOutput("all"))
server <- function(input, output,session) {
   prepGraph <- reactiveVal(NULL)
   output$all <- renderUI({
      items <- list()
      for(iCode in 1:length(plotNames)){
          items[[iCode]] <- plotOutput(plotNames[iCode])
      }
      for(code in plotNames){
        cat("\ntestParent:",code)
        output[[code]] <- renderPlot({
            cat("\ntestRender:",code)
            plot(1,main=code)
        })
      }

      prepGraph(TRUE)
      return(do.call(tagList,items))
  })
}
test <- shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Returns three identitical plots titled "plot3" and on the command line:

> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3842
>
> testParent: plot1
>
> testParent: plot2
>
> testParent: plot3
>
> testRender: plot3
>
> testRender: plot3
>
> testRender: plot3

How can I do a loop for `renderPlot` on the different `code`s ?

Environment: R 3.6.3 on Ubuntu 20.04.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is due to lazy evaluation.  Replace `for` loop with `lapply` and it will work.  Try this

```
library("shiny")
plotNames <- c("plot1", "plot2","plot3")
ui <- basicPage(uiOutput("all"))
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  prepGraph <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  output$all <- renderUI({
    items <- list()
    lapply(1:(length(plotNames)), function(iCode){
    # for(iCode in 1:length(plotNames)){
      items[[iCode]] <<- plotOutput(plotNames[iCode])
    })
    lapply(plotNames, function(code){
    # for(code in plotNames){
      cat("\ntestParent:",code)
      output[[code]] <- renderPlot({
        cat("\ntestRender:",code)
        plot(1,main=code)
      })
    })
    
    prepGraph(TRUE)
    return(do.call(tagList,items))
  })
}
test <- shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint and the explanation. It does work. For future users, knowing that it was a lazy evaluation problem I found github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/532#issuecomment-48008956 to be helpful though local({}) around everything in the for loop did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Just specifying the environment in `renderPlot` call fixes it.

Defining an environment:

```
 locEnv <- rlang::env(code=code)
```

Final minimal example with call to this environment in `renderPlot` :

```
library("shiny")
plotNames <- c("plot1", "plot2","plot3")
ui <- basicPage(uiOutput("all"))
server <- function(input, output,session) {
    prepGraph <- reactiveVal(NULL)
    output$all <- renderUI({
        items <- list()
        for(iCode in 1:length(plotNames)){
            items[[iCode]] <- plotOutput(plotNames[iCode])
        }
        for(code in plotNames){
            cat("\ntestParent:",code)
            locEnv <- rlang::env(code=code)
            output[[code]] <- renderPlot({
                cat("\ntestRender:",code)
                plot(1,main=code)
            },env=locEnv)
        }
        prepGraph(TRUE)
        return(do.call(tagList,items))
    })
}
test <- shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This doesn't explain why the normal call doesn't work though ...